Approximating an $L^1$ function with Riemann sums
Note: Here all functions are genuine functions, i.e. pointwise defined measurable functions instead of defined only a.e.
Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be an arbitrary $L^1$ function. Of course, $f$ is not Riemann integrable in general. However, can we find some sequence of tagged partitions that approximates the integral of $f$ in Riemann sense?
Question: Does there exist a sequence of partitions $\mathcal P_n = \{a^n_0, \dots, a^n_{k_n}\}$ of $[0, 1]$ with $\|P_n\| := \sup_i (a^n_{i+1} - a^n_i) \to 0$,
and for each $0 \leq i \leq k_n$, some $t^n_i \in [a^n_i, a^n_{i+1}]$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{k_n -1} (a^n_{i+1} - a^n_i) \, f(t^n_i) = \int_0^1 f?$$
Remark: I wonder if a probablistic method would work…

As you suggested below, can’t you get an answer from LebDiff+VitCov?

@AnthonyQuas It seems like that indeed works in general, one just has to deal with the annoying extra partition cells not given by the combination, but this can be done easily with naive bounds.

One can also use Lusin theorem.
